# dropdown list validation using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, jquery-validate

I want to validate a `dropdownlist` with jQuery. My code is:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown">
    <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True"> - Select State - </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AL">AL</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AK">AK</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AZ">AZ</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AR">AR</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CA">CA</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CO">CO</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="CT">CT</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

My jQuery validation is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        rules:  <%=ddlstate.UniqueID %>: {
            required: "*"
        }
    },
    messages: <%=ddlstate.UniqueID %>: {
        required: "*" 
        },
    });
```

Comment: hey not "ddlstate.UniqueID" make it ClientID

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Add a method called dropdownvalidator which will validate the dropdown

```
$.validator.addMethod("dropDownValidator", function (value, element, parameters) {
        return (value != '0');
});
```

And specify the dropdownvalidator method in the rule as below

```
rules: {
    myDropdown: {
        dropDownValidator: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If($("#ddlstate").Val() =="0")
{
    alert("Please select state");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to leave the default value as "" for it to work.

```xml
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown">
    <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"> - Select State - </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="AL">AL</asp:ListItem>
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("state", function(value, element) { 
  return /A-ZA-Z/.test(value); 
}, "Please select a state");

$("#aspnetForm").validate();

<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstate" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown state">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Databinding to populate your form you can manually add a ListItem with empty string as the value and add the **required** attribute to the dropdownlist.  Then jquery validator will fail validation if they don't select another item from the list.

```
//aspx.cs code if using databinding
myList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("", ""));

// aspx code
<asp:DropDownList ID="myList" runat="server" required="true">/asp:DropDownList> 

// js code
var validator = $("#Form1").validate();
```